# Linux header files referenced by mac80211 missing

Tags: kernel

I am using kernel 3.2.0-24-generic. I need to modify source files of ath9k and mac80211. One of the files in mac80211 refers to a few linux header files such as linux/slab.h, linux/skbuff.h, linux/etherdevice.h, linux/if_arp.h and so on. I have installed the latest headers but still these are missing. Where can I download these header files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you just need to point things to the right place?

```
$ find /usr/src/ -iname slab.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-24-generic/include/linux/slab.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-24/include/linux/slab.h

$ dpkg -S /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-24/include/linux/slab.h
linux-headers-3.2.0-24: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-24/include/linux/slab.h
```

So as long as you have the linux-headers-3.2.0-24 package, you should be good to go.

Also, if you update your question with the command you're running to compile the module you're modifying it may be helpful, because modules need to be compiled a specific way (I'm no expert, I'm hoping someone notices it and tells us how it's done).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I needed to include the folder under directories to be searched.